# Assign CSV values to class attributes, process output to csv using abstract classes

Tags: python, csv, class, abstract, abc

This question is a bit confusing so bear with me, it also has to be done with pure Python and no third-party modules.

I can't seem to assign the correct datatype to the CSV values and assign them to the class attributes.

I've tried every way I know, looked around for a few days for an answer...

The value error when FLOAT assigned the "line[4]", and the TypeError if I don't cast the variable.

I've also tried assigning them to new variables and casting the datatype. I think it is due to the rstrip() and strip() function output.

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

**Expected output:**

```
------- Resident ID: {self._id} -------
Gross: {self.gross}
Net: {self.net}
Tax: {self.tax}

------- Holiday ID: {self._id} -------
Gross: {self.gross}
Net: {self.net}
Tax: {self.tax}
Visa: {self._visa}
YTD: {self._year_to_date}
```

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from datetime import date #To assign <timestamp> for export_summary()
from typing import List

class PayRecord(ABC):
    def __init__(self, id: int, hours:float, rates:float):
        self._id = id
        self._hours = hours
        self._rates = rates

    @abstractmethod
    def get_details(self): 
        pass

    @property
    def id(self):
        return self._id

    @property
    def gross(self):
        return (self._hours * self._rates)

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def tax(self):
        return self.tax

    @property
    def net(self):
        return (self.gross - self.tax)
        
class ResidentPayRecord(PayRecord):
    def __init__(self, id: int, hours:float, rates:float):
        super().__init__(id, hours, rates)

    def get_details(self):
        return f"------- Resident ID: {self._id} -------\n\nGross: {self.gross}\nNet: {self.net}\nTax: {self.tax}\n"

    @property
    def tax(self):
        return calc_res_tax(self.gross)

class WorkingHolidayPayRecord(PayRecord):
    def __init__(self, id: int, hours:float, rates:float, visa: str, year_to_date:float):
        super().__init__(id, hours, rates)
        self._visa = visa
        self._year_to_date = year_to_date

    @property
    def visa(self):
        return self._visa

    @property
    def year_to_date(self):
        return self._year_to_date

    @property
    def tax(self):
        return calc_wh_tax(self.gross, self._year_to_date)

    def get_details(self):
        return f"------- Holiday ID: {self._id} -------\n\nGross: {self.gross}\nNet: {self.net}\nTax: {self.tax}\nVisa: {self._visa}\nYTD: {self._year_to_date}"


def calc_res_tax(gross: float):

    A_eff = [0.19,0.2342,0.3477,0.345,0.39,0.47]
    b_Eff =[0.19,3.213,44.2476,41.7311,103.8657,352.788]
    if (gross > -1 and gross <= 72):
        resTax = A_eff[0] * gross - b_Eff[0]
        return resTax
    if (gross > 72 and gross <= 361):
        resTax = A_eff[1] * gross - b_Eff[1]
        return resTax
    if (gross > 361 and gross <= 932):
        resTax = A_eff[2] * gross - b_Eff[2]
        return resTax
    if (gross > 932 and gross <= 1380):
        resTax = A_eff[3] * gross - b_Eff[3]
        return resTax
    if (gross > 1380 and gross <= 3111):
        resTax = A_eff[4] * gross - b_Eff[4]
        return resTax
    if (gross > 3111 and gross <= 999999):
        resTax = A_eff[5] * gross - b_Eff[5]
        return resTax
    
def calc_wh_tax(gross:float, year_to_date:float):
    rate = [0.15,0.32,0.37,0.45]
    if (year_to_date > -1 and year_to_date <= 37000):
        whTax = gross * rate[0]
        return whTax
    if (year_to_date > 37000 and year_to_date <= 90000):
        whTax = gross * rate[1]
        return whTax
    if (year_to_date > 90000 and year_to_date <= 180000):
        whTax = gross * rate[2]
        return whTax
    if (year_to_date > 180000 and year_to_date <= 9999999):
        whTax = gross * rate[3]
        return whTax    

def import_pay_records(file:str):
    records = []

    with open(file,"r") as f:
        next(f)
        for line in f:
            line = line.rstrip().split(',')
            id = int(line[0])
            hours = float(line[1])
            rates = float(line[2])
            visa = str(line[3])
            year_to_date = float(line[4])
            app = id,hours,rates,visa,year_to_date
            rec = [string for string in app if string != '']
            records.append(rec)
            create_pay_record(id,hours,rates,visa,year_to_date)


        return records

def create_pay_record(id:int, hours:float, rates:float, visa:str, year_to_date:float):
    
    r: ResidentPayRecord = ResidentPayRecord(id,hours,rates)
    wh: WorkingHolidayPayRecord = WorkingHolidayPayRecord(id,hours,rates,visa,year_to_date)

    print(r.get_details())
    print(wh.get_details())

def write_summary(file:str, records:List[PayRecord], to_console:bool):
    """The function must accept a list of PayRecord objects and write the Id, Gross, Net, and Tax amounts of a pay record to a comma delimited values (.csv) file"""
    pass

def main():
    records = import_pay_records("import\\employee-payroll-data.csv")
    write_summary("export\\export-data.csv",records,True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Import Data**:
There's more duplicate, but it doesn't matter. Just as an example.

```
EmployeeId,Hours,Rate,Visa,YearToDate
1,2,25,,
1,3,25,,
1,4,25,,
1,5,32,,
1,6,32,,
2,2,25,417,47520.0
2,2,25,417,47520.0
2,2,25,417,47520.0
```

Comment: Can you maybe post one example line and the line after rstrip()?

Comment: There are meant to be duplicate values in the CSV, however as an example.. When printing the line with rstrip() and split(','), the output looks like ``['1', '6', '32', '', '']
['2', '2', '25', '417', '47520.0']`` When printing from the list comprehension, it removes the extra quotations, that's all. When printing "line" without rstrip() and split(), it throws `ValueError: could not convert string to float: ','`

Comment: I added the import data for reference.

Comment: Okay so the issue is that csv contains some empty values right? E.g. "1,2,3,,,,"
Then you should probably replace those empty string in your list with some value. You can not convert an empty string "" to a float since the string has to obviously be some kind of number.

Comment: There are two types of Pay Records, the record that is missing two values is meant to remain empty, though now I understand what you mean so that would make sense. In that case, would it be better to separate them into their respective [PayRecord] categories? By replace the empty string, you mean place a float of "0.0" or something to that effect?

Comment: Yes you have to write some lines of code for the case these values remain empty. "" can not be converted to float because which number should it be? 0 , -1, ...?

Comment: I get you now, yeah it should be any non-meaningful value in that case, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems if that some fields are empty and `float('')` actually raise that `ValueError`

So you should test for empty values before trying to convert:

```
year_to_date = float(line[4]) if line[4].strip() != '' else 0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

After the .split() line, replace the empty strings with some number, e.g:

```
line = [string if string else '0' for string in line]
```

Then every list element can be castet to float.

Btw CSV files can also be read with pythons CSV Reader module ([Link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html))

Comment: Thanks for the help but I'm not sure how to use this, it still throws `ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''`, I'll use the solution above, unless you have another suggestion also! Regardless, still very appreciated, I'll keep it in mind for next time.

Comment: Did you write line = [..], i did not write it explicitly but added it. Anyway both solutions should work fine

Comment: OH! No I didn't, I will give that a go also, we will see.